# C - reverse a number

Tags: c, algorithm, reverse

I am coding in C on linux, and I need to reverse a number. (EG: 12345 would turn into 54321), I was going to just convert it into a string using itoa and then reverse that, as it's probably a lot easier with string manipulation, however it turns out itoa is non standard and isn't included in gcc. Is there a way of doing a binary rotation style thing on decimal numbers and if not what approach should I take?

Comment: You can use `sprintf()` as an alternative to `itoa()`: `sprintf(output, "%d", input)`.

Comment: Nothing is "included in gcc", since it's just a compiler. If you want to use `itoa()`, I'm pretty sure that will compile on any platform.

Comment: Perhaps not (quite) an exact duplicate, but certainly my answer to a previous question applies here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819608/179910

Comment: `itoa` is a standard C thing, it's declared in <stdlib.h>

Comment: @Hassan compilers include libraries with all the functions such as itoa, and printf, I can guarantee that using itoa won't compile with gcc.

Comment: @piokuc: What C standard includes that? It seems to be absent at least through C99.

Comment: @JerryCoffin really? I'm surprised they take out stuff from stdlib.h, I need to check it...

Comment: @piokuc: I'm reasonably certain no C standard every allowed `stdlib.h` to declare `itoa`.

Comment: @handuel What I meant was, it's not technically part of the compiler, but part of the standard library for the platform you're compiling for. And whether you're compiling for Linux, Mac, or Windows, `atoi()` should be available to you.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It seems you are right. Never mind, I don't use `atoi` anyway, I use `stringstream`.

Comment: @Hassan No it shouldn't, it isn't part of the C99 standard, and it is part of the libraries included with the compiler.

Comment: @handuel Okay, well whether or not it "should", it *is* available on the platforms I mentioned (I've used it on those platforms with a normal gcc or clang installation).

Answer (score 13):

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int rev=0,rem;
while(n>0)
{
    rem=n%10; //take out the remainder .. so it becomes 5 for 12345
    rev=rev*10+rem; //multiply the current number by 10 and add this remainder.
    n=n/10; //divide the number. So it becomes 1234.
}
printf("%d",rev);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
                 int rev=0,n;
                 scanf("%d",&n);
                 while(n)
                 {
                         rev=10*rev+n%10;
                         n/=10;
                 }
                 printf("result=%d",rev);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it without strings.

```
fkt()
   {
    int i = 12345;

    int n = 0;
    int x;
    char nr[10];
    char *p = &nr[0];

    while(i != 0)
    {
        x = i % 10;
        i = i/10;
        n = n * 10 + x;
        *p = x+'0';
        p++;
    }

    *p = 0;

    printf("%d   %s\n", n, nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use strings, you can use sprintf to do what itoa does.

```
int k = 12345;
char str[40];
sprintf(str,"%d",k);
```

Then reverse the string and convert it back to int using atoi or sscanf.

Comment: In general you use snprintf over sprintf to avoid buffer overruns.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl generally yes, but in this specific use case the length of the string is limited by the size of the integer N as log_10(2^N) + 1

Comment: While that's true, I'd prefer that nobody used sprintf, ever ;-) or at least first explained the potential problems to new coders.

Answer (score 0):

`iota()` is not a standard C function, but `snprintf()` serves the purpose just as well.

```
/* assume decimal conversion */
const char * my_itoa (int input, char *buffer, size_t buffersz) {
    if (snprintf(buffer, sz, "%d", input) < sz) return buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the input cannot be negative, you can use an unsigned type:

```
unsigned long long irev (unsigned input) {
    unsigned long long output = 0;
    while (input) {
        output = 10 * output + input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Reversing the input may result in a value that no longer fits the input type, so the return result attempts to use a wider type. This may still fail if `unsigned` and `unsigned long long` have the same width. For such cases, it is probably easiest to use a string to represent the reversed value. Or, if the only goal is to print the number, you can just use a loop to print the digits in reverse order.

```
void print_irev (unsigned input) {
    if (input) {
        do {
            putchar('0' + input % 10);
            input /= 10;
        } while (input);
    } else {
        putchar('0');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Can the input be negative?

Answer (score 0):

you can use stack to do this,

```
struct node
{
  char character;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *list_head,*neos;

main()
{
  list_head=NULL;
  char str[14];
  int number,i;
  scanf("%d",&number);     

  sprintf(str,"%d",number);  //here i convert number to string
 for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)  //until the end of the string
 {
   add_to_stack(str[i]);   //i take every character and put it in the stack
 }
 print_the_number();
```

}

attention here,in stack the item
which is added last,
it taken out first,
that why it works..

```
void add_to_stack(char charac)
{
  neos=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  neos->character=charac;
  neos->next=list_head;
  list_head=neos;
}

void print_the_number()
{
   struct node *ptr;
   ptr=list_head;
   while(ptr!=NULL)
   {
     printf("%c",ptr->character);
     ptr=ptr->next;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()    
{ 

int dig,n,rev=0;`
cout<<"enter number";
cin>>n;
while(n!=0)
{   
dig=n%10;
rev=rev*10+dig;
n=n/10; }

if(n==0){
cout<<"palindrome of zeros "; 
}
 if(rev==1)
{
cout<<"reverse of 10 is 01";
}
//since exception occurs when user inputs 10 or 0s
else
{
 cout<<"reverse of the number is ";
 cout<<rev;

}

getch();
}
```

Comment: Since, we are unable to reverse 0 or 10 because of the logic so we need to handle such exception using if else.

Comment: The question asks about C, not C++.

Comment: Is there any other better solution for reversing trailing zeros after a digit? For an instance, reverse of '5000 'returns '5' by the above logic, though the reverse out to be '0005'

Comment: I'd say the "answer" to the trailing zero problem is either (a) convert the number to a string and reverse the string, or (b) just don't worry about it, since "reverse the digits" is a pretty artificial, made-up problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

their are two methods

> method 1 :

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int rev=0,rem;
while(n>0)
{
    rem=n%10;
    rev=rev*10+rem; 
    n=n/10; 
}
cout<<rev;
```

> method 2:

```
cin>>n; // size of array
    
    int a[n+1]={0};
    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
    
    for(i=n;i>0;i--)
    cout<<a[i];
```