# Trying to print out the name of a number w/o arrays

Tags: objective-c, loops, int, switch-statement

I'm trying to reverse a number which a user inputs so that I can print it out in the correct order. Say the user inputs 957, the program should print out
nine
five
seven
However, I don't understand how I should go about actually flipping the number. Here's what I have so far:

```
int num;
    int revNum;
    int rem;
    printf("Input a number:");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    while(num!=0)
    {

        rem = num%10;
        revNum = revNum*10+rem;
        num/=10;
        switch(rem)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("zero\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("one\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("two\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("three\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("four\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("five\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("six\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("seven\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("eight\n");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("nine\n");
                break;
        }

    }
```

In which rem is remainder, revNum is the number reversed, and num is the number. Please help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** I missed the "without arrays" in the question title, I'll leave the answer here anyways...

If your problem is reversing the number, then [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447226/c-reverse-a-number). You have to first reverse the number, and then either take your algorithm with the `switch/case` to print it, or use `NSNumberFormatter` as described below.

#### Original Answer:

You have tagged your question Objective-C, but your code is pure C. Let's first make it a bit cleaner by actually using Objective-C:

Use `NSNumberFormatter` instead of your switch statement:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
```

You can now convert numbers to strings with `[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(rem)]`, it also works for different locales.

Now that we have `NSString` objects, we can throw them in an array:

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while(num!=0) {
    int rem = num%10;
    num/=10;
    [strings addObject:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(rem)]];
}
```

You can now iterate over the strings in reverse:

```
(for NSString *s in strings.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

Or simply reverse the array without a loop:

```
NSArray *result = strings.reverseObjectEnumerator.allObjects
```

Comment: The reason I can't use arrays is simply because we haven't yet learned them in the class I'm taking. The class is objective c, which is why I thought this code was obj c.

Comment: @user2967004 I have added some more info and a link to another answer that should help you solve the problem. As to whether your code is C or Objective-C, it's both. Objective-C is a superset of C, therefor all C code is also valid Objective-C code.