# C: Decimal Value

Tags: c, numbers, reverse

Can any one help me sort out one problem, i have to reverse a number without using array(int/char) for storing them.

```
input1 = 123
output1 = 321
input2 = 2300
output2 = 0032
```

I am trying to find the solution but 0 got erased while printing so i thought of octal conversion but still no solution, so i went with the decimal places and i made the 23 to 0.0032. Now my problem is how can i extract the 0032 from that part.

Is there any possible way to achieve this without using array(int/char), with that it will be easy.

Comment: Show your code to date.

Comment: do you want a code or logic will do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - reverse a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447226/c-reverse-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
 {
    int number =3200;
    int temp;
        while (number >0)
        {
        temp= number%10;
        printf("%d",temp);
        number = number/10;
        }

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use recursion to solve this problem, without using any array in fact u could also reverse a string without using any array using recursion. This code works for both numbers and strings and it has no arrays:

```
char reverse(int a)
    {
    char c,d; 
    if(a=='\n') 
        return 0;  
    c=getchar();  
    d=reverse(c);  
    putchar(a);  
    return (c);  
    }  
int main()  
    {  
    char c;  
    scanf("%c",&c);  
    reverse(c);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for a start try this.

```
int n, l;
char nBuf[126];
n = 1230010;
l = sprintf(nBuf, "%d", n );
while( l >= 0 )
    printf("%c", nBuf[l--] );
```

Though if you are taking input from stdin take it as string rathar than as int or long.

Edit - for not using array

```
   int n = 123;

        while(n) {
                printf("%d", n%10);
                n/=10;
        }
```

I am assuming to get a value of this sort "output2 = 0032" it is better of being a string, else formatting complications turns up with input value length and format left space with zeros etc etc.

Comment: Just for your concern, you are using an array but what if i dont want to use array. Is it possible then to print the reverse ?

Answer (score 0):

This becomes fairly easy if you know that you can represent numbers like so:

```
x = a_0 + a_1 * b^1 + a_2 * b^2 + ...
a_i are the digits
b is the base
```

To extract the lowest digit, you can use the remainder: `x % b`
Dividing by the base "removes" the last digit. That way you can get the digits in order lowest to highest.

If you reverse the digits then the lowest becomes the highest. Looking at below transformation it's easy to see how to incrementally build up a number when the digits come in order highest to lowest:

```
x = a_0 + b * (a_1 + b * (a_2 + ...
```

You start of with 0, and for each digit you multiply with the base and then add the digit.

In pseudo code:

```
output = 0
while input != 0
  digit = input % base
  input = input / base ;; integer division
  output = output * base + digit
end
```

If you want to store leading zeros, then you need to either store the digits in an array, or remember for how many steps of above loop the output remained zero:

```
output = 0
zeros = 0
while input != 0
  digit = input % base
  input = input / base ;; integer division
  output = output * base + digit
  if output == 0
    zeros = zeros + 1
  end
end
```

To print that you obviously need to print `zeros` zeros and then the number.

---

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/eu8rme), relevant code:

```
unsigned reverse(
    unsigned input,
    unsigned const base,
    unsigned * const zeros) {
  unsigned output = 0;
  unsigned still_zero = 0;
  for (; input != 0; input/=base) {
    output *= base;
    output += input % base;
    if (output == 0) {
      ++still_zero;
    }
  }
  if (zeros != NULL) {
    *zeros = still_zero;
  }
  return output;
}

void print_zeros(unsigned zeros) {
  for (; zeros != 0; --zeros) {
    printf("0");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion allows for a simple solution.  A small variation on [@vishu rathore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32678143/2410359)

```
void rev_dec(void) {
  int ch = getchar();
  if (isdigit(ch)) {
    rev_dec();
  }
  if (ch >= 0) putchar(ch);
}

int main(void) {
  rev_dec();
  return 0;
}  

input  
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
output  
9876543210987654321098765432109876543210
```