# checking if a number is mirror of the other (its reverse)

Tags: c, function

given a function that takes two numbers: Mirror( num 1, num 2)

how do I check if num2 is the mirror of number 1? IN C

for example if num 1= 523 num2=325  return 1: it's its mirror otherwise returns 0 
more examples
num1=566 num2:566 returns false 
num1=500 num2=005 return true

the length of the two numbers is unknown

Comment: Are they always 3 digit numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - reverse a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447226/c-reverse-a-number)

Comment: I hope that this is not your home work in school

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the reverse and then compare the result with your other number.

```
int mirror(int n,int m)
{
  int rev=0;
  while(n>0)
    {
      rev*=10;
      rev+=n%10;
      n/=10;
    }

  return rev==m ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Will Not work for input like 290 and 92.

Here 290 reverse will be 92 which will make it mirror image acc to above algo.

Which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Will Not work for input like 290 and 92. Here 290 reverse will be 92 which will make it mirror image if we check by just reversing the num. Which is wrong.

We can correct it by making sure that we reverse the smaller of these numbers and then checking e.g. for 29 and 920, 29 being smaller will give rev = 92 which is not same as 920 and hence the correct answer.

```
int mirror(int s, int l){
// swap the numbers so that s is always smaller than l
    if (s > l) {
        int temp = s;
        s = l;
        l = temp;
    }

    int rev=0;
    while(s > 0){
        rev*=10;
        rev+=n%10;
        n/=10;
    }

    return rev==l ? 1 : 0;
}
```